# Value of current in the given circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Since, point B is connected to Ground, Should not current exist only in the branch ABG, and zero current in the branch BCDE, as current chooses least resistive path to move to lower potential.

Solution for this circuit shows current $I=\frac{50}{5+7+10+3}$, which means current exists in the Branch BCDE.

According to me, it should have been $I=\frac{50}{5+7}$, what am I missing?

Solution is at https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/in-the-circuit-shown-the-point-b-is-earthed-the-potential-at-the-point-a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since, point B is connected to Ground, Should not current exist only in the branch ABG, and zero current in the branch BCDE,

No.

$$I=\frac{V}{R}$$

So if node C isn't also at ground then there is non-zero potential difference across the 10-ohm resistor and current will flow through it.

Similarly, if node D isn't at the same potential as node C then there is a potential difference across the 3-ohm resistor and current will flow through it as well.

> as current chooses least resistive path to move to lower potential.

Current flows through all resistors that have a potential difference across them.

The principle "current flows through the path of least resistance" is only really applicable when there is a very large difference in the resistance of two parallel paths (say 1000 ohms in one path, and 1 ohm in the other --- in which case there is 1000 times as much current in the 1-ohm path than the 1000-ohm path and it's often {but not always} reasonable to ignore the current in the high-resistance path).

You should also not assume that ground is always the lowest potential node in a circuit.

Comment: Is not 10 ohm resistor connected to Ground one one side and at the other side, it is connected to 0 potential side of battery? So, how does non-zero potential difference exist for 10 ohm resistor?

Comment: @Sahil, the negative terminal of the battery isn't attached to 0 V, it's attached to node E.

Comment: So, we cannot assume that node is at 0Volt

Comment: @Sahil, No, why do you think you can assume that?

Comment: I feel like getting it, Ground is always 0, while negative terminal of battery cannot be treated like 0, battery(here) just maintains 50V across its terminals (be it 100V and 50V) or (60V and 10V)

Comment: Or +30 and -20. **You should also not assume that ground is always the lowest potential node in a circuit.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117246/discussion-between-sahil-and-the-photon).

Comment: Could you please shed more light on "You should also not assume that ground is always the lowest potential node in a circuit."?

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't ignore the possibility that the potential at a node is less than 0. For example, in your problem you'll find that the potential at node E is -26 V. You shouldn't get hung up on this. -26 V is just as valid a value for the potential as +15 V.

Comment: I am crystal clear with this now.